# Understanding the Lemma 2 of Calculus of Variations

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

[Lemma 2 of the Calculus of Variations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKDnP.png)

I''m trying to understand the lemma but I don't understand why is that $h(x)$ is defined as $$\int_a^x [\alpha(\xi)-c]d\xi$$

In other words, I don't get the point why is that $h(x)$ is defined based on the function $\alpha$ if $h(x)$ can be any function.

How can I know that with that function, $h(x)$ can be expressed any function derivable in $[a,b]$?

Comment: You just pick convenient $h$ to get the result: $$\int_a^b (\alpha(x)-c)^2\, dx = \int_a^b (\alpha(x)-c)h'(x)\, dx = 0$$ implies that $\alpha(x)-c = 0$.

Comment: But the lemma is based in __every__ $h(x)$ with that conditions, I don't get the point how defining conveniently in that form you can express __every__ function $h(x)$

Comment: I don't know what is troubling you, we don't want to prove anything about $h$'s, we want to prove something about $\alpha$. If all plumbers can fix water pipes, I don't have to call every plumber in the world when my sink is not working, I can just call my neighbor Luigi the Plumber to fix it. If the analogy is not clear enough, "$\alpha$ is constant" is my broken sink that needs fixing, $h$'s are plumbers who can fix it, $h(x) = \int_a^x(\alpha(\xi)-c)\,d\xi$ is my neighbor Luigi who I call to do the job.

Comment: My trouble is that it seems that defining in that way $h(x)$ and following the deduction, the proof of $\alpha$ is just based in a specific type of $h(x)$. For me, by now, is like trying to demonstrate the Lemma, for example, just when $h(x)$ is a constant o a linear function...

Comment: What about my analogy doesn't work for you? It is not _specific type_ of $h$, it is one particular $h$ out of infinitely many. The assumptions are "**for all** $h$ such and such, this formula is true", the proof is "ok, if it works **for all** $h$, then it works for this $h$", and finally the conclusion is "look, this one of the many $h$'s I could have chosen helps me prove the lemma". I think you are confusing what are assumptions and what is to be proven.

Comment: Let me give you another (pretty useless) lemma: "Let $x\in\mathbb R$ such that for all integers $n$ we have $nx = 0$. Then $x = 0$." _Proof._ Assumption says that $nx = 0$ for all integers $n$ and $1$ is an integer. Then $x = 1x = 0$. QED. As you can see, we picked one integer out of infinitely many that helps us prove what we want with least amount of effort. In your proof, convenient $h$ was chosen so that you prove what you want.

Comment: I see the analogy as: Let $x\in\mathbb R$ such that for all integers $n$ we have $x+n=x$ and the proof is: well, $0$ is an integer, so if with $0$ it works, with the rest of the integers will work, and of course that's not the case...

Comment: That does not work. To begin with, your example does not contain anything to be proven, it is not of the form "if [assumptions] then [conclusion]". What you did is assume something then tried to prove _assumption_! That is not how proofs work! Notice that in my example we have [assumptions] = "$x\in\mathbb R$ is such that..." and [conclusion] = "$x = 0$". Your sentence does not have such a structure, so there is nothing to be proven.

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha(x)$ is not $c$ all the time, then $\alpha(x) - c$ is not zero all the time.  An easy way to detect this is to square it and integrate.  Conveniently, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, the given $h(x)$ satisfies $h'(x) = \alpha(x)-c$.  So $\int_a^b (\alpha(x) -c)h'(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ **is** squaring it and integrating (which is what the last display in your imgur link says).

The integral is also like a dot product.  One way to get a large dot product from a nonzero vector is to dot the vector with itself.  This choice of $h$ produces an integral that is the dot product of $\alpha(x) -c$ with itself.  So if $\alpha(x) -c$ is not "the zero vector", we get a "large" (positive) dot product.  Since we can distribute $h'(x)$ and actually do the integrals ("on the one hand") getting zero, we end up showing that the dot product is zero, so the vector is zero, so $\alpha(x) = c$.

Comment: But the lemma is based in __every__ $h(x)$ with that conditions, I don't get the point how defining conveniently in that form you can express __every__ function $h(x)$

Comment: @JoanJ.Cáceres : No.  The lemma says "if $\alpha(x)$ is nice and (some integral) holds for every function $h$ having nice endpoints, **then** result."  This means you may assume that it works for any function you care to write down that happens to have nice endpoints.  This is why the proof checks "$h(a) = h(b) = 0$ after picking an $h$, so that we know we have chosen an $h$ for which the displayed integral in the lemma statement holds.